# Jenkins disable build now

Tags: jenkins

I need to disable "Build now" option on Jenkins, I have a job building a branch and deploy SNAPSHOTs to a server. I need a production Job, that generates only stable versions, using maven release, but for this job I think the best approach is disable "Build Now" option and use only Maven Release. So Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Authorization strategy plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin) to disallow running the job. If configured right - no one will see "Build Now" button. Another options is [Job Restrictions plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin), but it looks a bit clumsy or simply not that good for this particular task.